# Retrieving data from sql database in Android app

Tags: android, mysql, sql, android-layout, user-interface

If you're pulling data from an sql database in an Android app, how are you supposed to implement that with your ui? I'm able to make a beautiful ui that links in-app elements, but I'm still confused as to how one would replicate a single UI element in a listed view. For example, twitter reuses the same box with text, a username, and a few buttons. Are they using an object created in an XML file? I'm very confused about how this works and would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Because when I try using an xml layout, and putting multiple copies in a listview, it becomes very buggy and slow. Thanks.

Comment: Either you are new to listviews or I didn't get your question. You want to create a list of items where each item has the same layout but different data, right?

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari that's exactly what I want to do. I'm confused as to what you're putting the data into and how you call that ui piece each time.

Comment: Firstly, I'd recommend using RecyclerView instead of a ListView. Google it, see and try to understand the examples given. If you have any doubts ask here. Basically you make a single .xml file for the whole list and re- use it for each list item with the help of a RecyclerView/ ListView using an appropriate adapter.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari alright thanks! So I'm right about the XML though, right? You would create your desirable layout  in an XML file and there are ways to scoop off extra unused space later when calling them to the recycle view. Hopefully that's accurate.

Comment: Yes correct about the xml part. But what unused space? What extra space??

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari the XML file in Android studio is the same size as the app page. Like the actual size of a post is half the page. So I wouldn't need to use a large portion of the XML file. I didn't think you could change the size?

Comment: Are u talking in terms of memory or filesize?

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari no in terms of designing the ui within the XML file. The physical size of the space I need for formatting a post is half the size of the XML page. Maybe I'm not doing something right? From my understanding, an xml file is always the size of the app. So if each post doesn't require all that space, how would you reflect that in the XML file?

Comment: You just need to give a your desired height & width to your item's root tag in the xml to make sure your single item doesn't take up the whole screen. Don't worry about the blank spaces left at the bottom of your layout in the preview. RecyclerView will understand that the layout of the item is as much as specified in width and height and there wont be any extra space in the final output.

Comment: Please practice examples and then ask questions, that way you'll get a better understanding doing it on your own.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari OK thanks. Sorry I'm relatively new to this stuff, I was just struggling to find anybody covering this issue. Perhaps I wasn't looking for the right things. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Most welcome! :)